# copy exe file while it's running?

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe

This following code in my bat file copy's the bat file while it's running into a correct directory in windows 7 but when I convert it to a exe script it no longer works. 
Can any one suggest a alternative ? Or any suggestions to why?

```
if not exist "%programfiles%\toolset\" (
    md "%programfiles%\toolset\"
    copy "%~f0" "%programfiles%\toolset\"
)
```

can any one else help I'm pretty sure it's not my converter tool I use as I have tried all the ones listed below but I think the script needs editing for it to function as exe application?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following nice tool

http://www.battoexeconverter.com/

since you are accessing programfiles you need to be admin

To do this run the cmd in admin mode and try to execute in command line

Comment: I've tried this and iexpress and advanced bat to exe converter it doesn't work I'm running as admin it works for the bat script but not the exe file

Answer (score 0):

Download this tool. It works well.

[Bat2Exe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8NGKD2_bHtIX0h3NV9zYktqNTQ/view?usp=sharing)

You can add administrator manifest to run as administrator when opening the exe file.

Comment: I don't think it's the tool as I've used 3 different converters and it just doesn't copy as exe form I've used iexpress advanced bat to exe converter & this tool as well I think the script needs to be changed some how to accommodate for the exe file

Answer (score 0):

I am a batch programmer just like you.

Personally I use this tool;

http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=ob2e

Nice tool, only requires a download, used it multiple times, never dissappointed me, and it is very legit, have no doubts about it!

Pringles

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer I've tried this tool too but it's not working for my exe script as your experienced in batch can you suggest how should edit my script so it functions in the exe Application..thanks!

Comment: Hmmmmmmm. I believe it is a problem with your code, as I have tried it, and no luck for me. I get an error message "The computer can not find the file path specified." Does it execute properly when it is saved as a ".bat"? If not it is definetly a problem with your code. If you can't run it as a .bat, notify me and I will further review your code.